# Can i use split_view with a delimiter that's comparable, but otherwise not related to the split range's value type?

Tags: c++, split, c++20, std-ranges

`std::ranges::split_view` works by taking a range that is to be split paired with a delimiter.

However, said delimiter is defined in quite a peculiar way - [it needs to be a `forward_range`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.split).

Fortunately, the standard allows the usage of `split_view` such that a range and a single element is passed. Notably, this is an example from the standard:

```cpp
string str{"the quick brown fox"};

for (auto word : views::split(str, ' ')) {
    cout << string_view(word) << '*';
}
```

As you can see, we can pass `' '` as a delimiter. To my knowledge, this works by employing the following constructor:

```cpp
template<forward_range R>
requires constructible_from<V, views::all_t<R>> 
         && constructible_from<Pattern, single_view<range_value_t<R>>>
constexpr explicit split_view(R&& r, range_value_t<R> e);
```

This allows us to pass an `std::string` as the range `R` and a `char` as the delimiter `e`. The `requires` clause ensures that this will work by checking whether `char` is the `range_value_t` of an `std::string` (it is) *and* if it's possible to create an `std::ranges::single_view<char>` (potentially to always delegate to the implementation that assumes that the delimiter is a range). Works wonders.

But what if I wanted to heavily customize my splitting behavior? For example, I wanted to split on **any whitespace**. Foolishly, I thought that this will work:

```cpp
struct Whitespace {
    auto operator==(char const c) const noexcept -> bool {
        return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    }

    friend auto operator==(char const c, Whitespace const ws) noexcept -> bool {
        return ws == c;
    }
} whitespace;

auto main() -> int {
    auto const text = std::string("3213 421 43 3 532 5 53 53 5 3535 5353");

    namespace views = std::ranges::views;

    auto numbers = text | views::split(whitespace);
}
```

But `Whitespace` is a type that is neither a range, not you can create an `std::ranges::single_view<char>` from it. And even if it was and if you could, there would be no way to retain its custom behaviors, given the fact that the mentioned constructor would convert it to plain, old `char`.

Can I somehow use `std::views::split` with a custom logic for splitting, let's say, ranges of `char`s?

Comment: I think you want something more like Range-v3's [`split_when`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/split_when.hpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `split_view` requires `indirectly_comparable<iterator_t<V>, iterator_t<Pattern>, ranges::equal_to>`, and `ranges::equal_to` requires `equality_comparable_with` (with an minor caveat not relevant here). The semantic requirements of that concept disallows non-transitive "equality" (i.e., `t1 == u`, `t2 == u` but `t1 != t2`), which is necessary for any `u` that matches more than one value.

It follows that all attempts to do such things either are IFNDR or have undefined behavior.